# LESS - file import loop - SyntaxError Recursive variable definition

Tags: css, less, syntax-error

I have this.

```
@imports: base variables, base mixins;

.loop(@index) when (@index >= 0){

    @dir_file : extract( @imports, @index );

    @dir : extract( @dir_file, 1 );
    @file: extract( @dir_file, 2 );

    @import "@{dir}/@{file}";

    .loop( @index - 1 );
}

.loop( length( @imports ) );
```

Which produces this

> > SyntaxError: Recursive variable definition for @dir_file in assets/less/project.less on line 19, column 1:
> >     18 
> >     19 .loop( length( @imports ) );

Essentially I am trying to loop over my array `@imports` and `@import` each LESS file. Not entirely sure if what I'm attempting to do is even possible? If it is, where am I going wrong?

Comment: This is not going to work. The `@import` statements are applied at the point of the mixin definition and not where you call/expand that mixin I.e. the content of the imported files becomes the content of the mixin body (it's not like you invoke a mixin and then the mixin executes its body statements incl. imports). Thus imports can't use any vars of the mixin since these vars do not even exist at that point. So whatever you do you need to find another way (in the particular case above I can't see how explicit listing of dirs and files is different from explicit imports of the said files).

Comment: seven-phases-max thanks for getting back to me. No particular reason, just trying to minimize lines of @imports.

Comment: *just trying to minimize lines of imports* - consider using the `glob` [plugin](http://lesscss.org/usage/#plugins-list-of-less-plugins).

Comment: I did use it, but the order in which they are imported is important to the project.

Comment: *I did use it, but the order* - I can guess, but as far as I can tell from your example it's only the order of dirs that matters (as it goes usually: "default/base stuff" then "custom/sub theme stuff" then "final/site/project stuff"). The order of individual files within each subset  rarely matters, so for your above example it's just `@import "base/*"; @import "custom/*";` and so on.

Comment: Gets tricky when your incorporating other libraries. And with LESS's lazy loading of variables order becomes more important. I am using UIKit and there is a specific batch of files that need to be loaded last. It's not a deal breaker, just a few more lines of code.

Comment: *And with LESS's lazy loading of variables order becomes more important.* - OK, Hmm, let's stop here (for the lazy-loading is contrary the thing that makes all this more easy). I guess there's fundamental misunderstanding in how we both treat this and it's impossible to resolve via comments.

Comment: *I am using UIKit and there is a specific batch of files that need to be loaded last.* - I can't find anything like this in their docs (nor can't see this in their source code). There's some SCSS hackery in UIKit, but in Less this (files forced to be imported last) would be a broken method (exactly because of the lazy-loading).

Comment: I am importing UIKit v2.27.4 into my project, basically only what I need. If you look in their `npm_module/uikit/dist/less/uikit.less:line47` there is a comment "// Need to be loaded last". Not so much "misunderstanding" as me using LESS for the first time and moving from SASS. If I'm honest I made the move because of UIKit's adoption and LESS's ability to use variable path names on `@import`'s. Anyway, have learnt a lot form these comments.

Comment: For the UIKit comment: this means these files to be placed last with the `uikit.less` itself, not within your whole project (thus this can;t affect anything else, including things possible to be imported with the `glob`). Also I wonder now how your mixin like above would help your with things like importing these UIKIt components (I suggested `glob` as something similar to above mixin i.e. as the helper to import files with regular patterns, not for importing *everything*). Well, never mind, as I already noted it's hard to cover all possible pitfalls w/o knowing all the details.

Comment: *... Less's ability to use variable path names on @import's.* - that seems weird, if importing files from some generic list would be one the main problems in some project I'd rather wrote a Node.js script generating a corresponding less file with all of these imports. (It's a really a tool-chain problem not a language problem).